# .attr("href") returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simplified version of my HTML

```
<div class="post-title-div">
    <a href="link" class="post-title">Link</a>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <img class="eye-icon" src="link.jpg"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $(".eye-icon").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).parent('.post-title-div').find(".post-title").attr("href");
  })
```

`alert(link)` returns undefined, why?

`$(this).parent('.post-title-div').find(".post-title")` by itself returns `[object Object]`

Comment: Have you tried parents instead of parent.

Comment: the jQueery $(this).parent('.post-title-div') will fail to find the div you want as - but jQueery returns a jQueery object, and even running a .find on a failed jQueery wont show any errors, such is the "forgiving" nature of jQueery ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parent`/`Parents`/`Closest` is not what you're after :

```
 $(".eye-icon").click(function(){

    var link = $(this).parent().prev().prev().find(".post-title").attr("href");
   alert(link)
  })
```

You don't have a common parent there.

http://jsbin.com/tupeta/edit?html,js,output

However , I suggest that you add a new container which will contain them all . something like :

```
<div class='wrapper'> 
 <div class="post-title-div">
    <a href="link" class="post-title">Link</a>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <img class="eye-icon" src="link.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

So now you can do :

```
 $(".eye-icon").click(function(){

    var link = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find(".post-title").attr("href");
   alert(link)
  })
```

Comment: Still giving `undefined` for some reason

Comment: `.post-title-div` isn't ancestor of `.eye-icon`

Comment: yep, new edit works. sad my post got downvoted to hell though. I thought `parent()` went up to find it

Answer (score 0):

The parent of the `<img>` is the nondescript `<div>` which surrounds it. jQuery then looks in that div for `'.post-title-div'`, doesn't find anything and returns an empty selector object. In that empty selector it then looks for `.post-title` and - naturally - doesn't find anything either. It then tries to read an attribute on the new, also empty, selector, which of course can't return anything useful.

The reason why `$(this).parent('.post-title-div').find(".post-title")` returns an `[object Object]` is because jQuery selectors never return undefined, they always return another selector, which can be an empty selector.